# Some characters in ssh are changed

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, centos

I have a virtual machine running on CentOS 6.5 and I wrongly did a `cat` of a compiled file (an apache module).

Since then, while I'm into the machine over ssh, it reads some characters differently. 
For instance, if I type `[` it shows `°` and if I type `]`it shows `é`

What happened? How can I fix it?

Thank you so much!

Comment: A new ssh session should fix this problem I would think, does it not? Using `reset` and/or `stty sane` might also help the current session.

Comment: Thank you guys, `reset` solved the issue!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
reset
```

to reset your console driver.

See [the reset manpage](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?reset+1) or [this guide from TLDP](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-4.html) complete with examples.